# simpleJdbcCall returning only 1 row

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, spring-jdbc

I have written a stored procedure in pl/pgsql and it is working fine in pgAdmin. And i am using simpleJBDCCall to call the procedure which returns a set of record. When i call the stored procedure from java using SimpleJdbcCall execute function only 1 row is returned to java, the same procedure when called in pgAdmin returns multiple rows.

my stored procedure is :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_instruments_list(userName varchar, OUT a int,out b int,out c int)
    RETURNS setof Record 
    AS
    $$
    DECLARE
       BEGIN
           RETURN query select 1,2,3;
           RETURN QUERY select 5,2,3;
           RETURN query select 6,2,3;
           return;
       END;
    $$
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

my java function to call the stored procedure is :

```
    public static void main(String[] a){

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/config/applicationContext-postgreSQL.xml");
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) applicationContext.getBean("pgJdbcTemplate");
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);

    jdbcCall.setSchemaName("dhapic");
    jdbcCall.setProcedureName("get_instruments_list");
    Map<String, String> inputParamater = new HashMap<>();
    inputParamater.put("userName", "dhanush");
    jdbcCall.returningResultSet("result", new RowMapper() {
        @Override
        public InstrumentList mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            InstrumentList instrumentList = new InstrumentList();
            instrumentList.setInstrumentId(rs.getInt(1));
            instrumentList.setInstrumentToken(rs.getInt(2)+"");
            instrumentList.setUserRole(rs.getInt(3)+"");
            return instrumentList;
        }
    });
    Map<String,Object> response = jdbcCall.execute(inputParamater);
    System.out.println("response"+response);
 }
```

JdbcTemplet values is pass using spring.

response object just contains 1 row, but i am expecting 3 rows. 
Please help me debug the problem.

Comment: What happens if you run the same SQL from `psql`?

Comment: I am able to get all the rows when i run it in psql (PgAdmin). problem is i am not able to get all the rows in java.

Comment: OK, and what is the exact SQL generated by Spring Templates for this query? Get it from the PostgreSQL log or the Spring logs.

Comment: {? = call dhapic.get_instruments_list(?, ?, ?)}     
this is what i got from callString.
is this what u asked?

Comment: OK, that's the JDBC-escaped query. Since it's using JDBC escapes, to get the actual SQL you'd need to go to the PostgreSQL logs with `log_statement` set to `all` in `postgresql.conf`. But it probably isn't worth it, that's good enough so long as you're really completely totally sure you're sending the exact same parameters.

Comment: any suggestions how i need to do this?

Comment: so you're sure you're using the same PgJDBC version as PostgreSQL?

Comment: I think your code would work if your stored proc returned a refcursor but you have defined the return as a setof record. My hunch is that it returns an array of records and you'd have to define your output parameter to handle this. You would need a custom implementation for this and you can base your code on the Oracle implementation available in the Spring JDBC Extensions project - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/blob/master/spring-data-oracle/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/oracle/SqlStructArrayValue.java

Comment: i am facing similar issue..any solution other than iterating over resultset